# How to use "Pull To Refresh" framework7 on the bottom?

Tags: javascript, pull-to-refresh, html-framework-7

I need to refresh the page of the application, but in the bottom.
Just drug it to the top.Maybe "Pull To Refresh" can be reverse?
How do i do that? Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it, reverse pull refresh by utilizing  "infinitescroll" class and "infinite" event

1. infinitescroll class

   ```
   <div class="page">
       <div class="page-content infinite-scroll" data-distance="100">
           ... 
       </div>
   </div>
   ```
2. applying "infinite" event

   $$('.infinite-scroll').on('infinite', function () {
     // get data from backend 
   }